# How to catch an ID of external plugin from AddThis.com in Jquery mobile website

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, addthis

I have used this plugin for share/follow button button . What i was trying is to add a class to a div that has  ID `at4m-mobile-container` . but I am not able to do this because what I have understood the problem is I am trying to add the class before the div is being created .

I tried `pageinit` and `pageshow` none of them worked .

**script**

```
addthis.layers({
    'theme': 'transparent',
        'share': {
        'position': 'left',
            'numPreferredServices': 5
    },
        'follow': {
        'services': [{
            'service': 'facebook',
            'id': ''
        }, {
            'service': 'google_follow',
            'id': ''
        }]
    },
        'whatsnext': {},
        'recommended': {}
});

$(document).on('pageinit', function () {
    var height = $(window).height();
    $('#at4m-mobile-container').addClass('bottom');


});
```

and the [**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/wLKh6/7/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: the only way is to `setTimeout()`. The plugin has no _init_ callback to be used to apply modifications. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/EfJg9/

Comment: but @Omar I cant see the Bottom class in the div being added after I run the code

Comment: @Omar this way I can not use it because actually I was trying to add some top padding using js to push down the footer to the bottom of the page . Because by default the footer has tendence to float over the the page that I don't want. And after i Increased the time it takes like 6 seconds to add the

Comment: Footer's height is 44px, add them straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add that code in `pagebeforeshow` of a specific page instead of `document` like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#my-page', function(){
    var height = $(window).height();
    $('#at4m-mobile-container').addClass('bottom');
});
```

There you should get the created div.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Vikram using page id always worked for me. If this doesn't work, you must be doing some other mistake.

Comment: Actually when I tried looking into the firebug . I saw that the div for the share/follow button is outside the page . SO what do you suggest I should do . I have the fiddle added in my question itself . Can you please look into it

Comment: Put that button inside a page, and your fiddle looked incomplete. It doesn't contain css `bottom`, neither the element with id `at4m-mobile-container`. So please fix that. @Vikram

Comment: I have updated the fiddle.. and for `at4m-mobile-container` I dont have to add that div its being written by the script . If you run the script and then look into firebug you can see the div with the id as `at4m-mobile-container`